# Google Checkout View Cart Button

Tags: view, shopping-cart, google-checkout

I'm trying to add a view cart button to my website that is using google checkout, does anyone know a trick to do this? I think I may need to use a special div with a class to create a button that will display the cart when clicked, I'm lost.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="product">
<input type="hidden" class="product-title" value="8x10 Product
<input type="hidden" class="product-price" value="19.95">
<a class="googlecart-add">Product Title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Google Checkout shopping cart has its own JavaScript and CSS APIs - you can use those to change the cart's appeareance and behavior to beter match yout website look and feel.

See this document for more info:

http://sites.google.com/site/checkoutshoppingcart/customising-cart-s-ui